# Action after mapview (swipe) animation stops

Tags: android, android-mapview

### The problem

I'm using a mapview with an overlay. When I swipe, the overlay has to be redrawn. But it just chooses some random point during the animation.

### The question

How can I make sure that I perform an action (in general) only *after* the mapview stopped moving?